# Visual Studio / MSBuild : Determine programatically if a solution needs to be built

Tags: visual-studio

I'm trying to find a way to determine programmaticaly if a solution is up-to-date or not (and I don't want to trigger a build in case it is not)

I'm using a visual studio solution with C++ and C# projects

I tried fiddling with VSIX and MSBuild, but without success

The only way I can think of so far is just to compare timestamps between input files and tlog files, but VS/MSBuild is already doing it, so maybe I can save the trouble of re-writng it

Thanks, Benny

Comment: Friend, do you mean that you need a function which returns a bool like Solution.IsUpToDate(). For this, as i know, there has no such method in assemblies provided by visual studio. Maybe you have to hand-coding it step by step.(get the file, get its timestamp and compare).

Comment: Lance, that's exactly what I'm looking for, even if it's code snippet, command line with args or something similar. The closest thing I could find is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.vcprojectengine.vcconfiguration.uptodate?view=visualstudiosdk-2017, but that is only for C++ projects